# Show that $f$ is a modular form for the congruence subgroup $\Gamma_0(N)$

Tags: modular-forms

> Let $f\in M_k(\text{SL2}(\mathbb{Z}))$ and
> $$
> f_N(\tau) :=\sum_{r=0}^{N-1}{f(\frac{\tau +r}{N})}
> $$
> then $f\in M_k(\Gamma_o(N))$

To check that $f\in M_k(\Gamma_o(N))$ I have to check that

$$
f_{\vert k \gamma} = f \; \text{for all }\gamma \in \Gamma_o(N)
$$

and $$f_{\vert k \alpha^{-1}} = \sum_{n=0}^{\infty}{a_n \exp{(\frac{2\pi i n}{N}})} \text{ for all }\gamma \in \text{SL2}(\mathbb{Z})\; .$$

By definition of $f_N$ it's N-periodic and therefore has a fourier series of the form

$$
\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}{c_n\exp(\frac{2\pi i n \tau}{N})}
$$

I had a hard time checking the conditions above as "simply" plugging in $\tau = \gamma \tau$ and using the transformation for modular forms of weight $k$ didn't help. Whats the best way to check both conditions ?

Would appreciate any help/hint

Comment: What is $r$ in the definition of $f_N$?

Comment: @Rachmaninov $f_N(\tau) :=\sum_{r=0}^{N-1}{f(\frac{\tau +r}{N})}$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$$U_N f=\frac1N \sum_{r=0}^{N-1}{f(\frac{z+r}{N})} = \sum_n a_{nN}(f) e^{2i\pi nz}, \qquad U_N = \prod_{p^k \| N} U_p^k$$

For $f\in M_k(\Gamma_0(m))$ $$ U_p f= T_p f-1_{p\ \nmid\ m} p^{k-1}f(pz)$$
where $T_p$ is the [Hecke operator](https://wstein.org/papers/generating_hecke/generating_hecke/node2.html) $M_k(\Gamma_0(m))\to M_k(\Gamma_0(m))$,

$$T_p f\in M_k(\Gamma_0(m)),\qquad f(pz) \in M_k(\Gamma_0(pm))$$ so that $U_p f\in  M_k(\Gamma_0(pm))$ and $$U_N f\in M_k(\Gamma_0(Nm))$$
In fact $U_N f\in M_k(\Gamma_0(m\prod_{p| N} p))$